# How to integrate a comment system in an ios app?

Tags: iphone, ios

Lets say my web server app is in drupal or wordpress, or even code igniter, how would one get about integrating a comment system? TSpecifically what I am trying to find out is if anyone was able to find a successful approach that would save some time as opposed to me going down the road of tying myself to a specific CMS content system.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question - could you clarify what the relation between your web server app and your iOS app is? Are you accessing a web server app via a native iOS app? Also, Wordpress, for example, already has a comment system built in, is there a reason why you're not using that?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. My ios APP has content that gets pulled from a CMS like wordpress. I also would like to allow the user to comment on stuff.Does this enntail me using the Wordpress comment system only? What if we decide to change the CMS later. Just was looking for a direction or approach on this matter. I would agree I did not do a good job explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing in some considerations here (by no means complete):

**Are users also accessing your content (and its comment system) via the website?**

- If so, you'll want to have a comment interface that is available on the website too, and the easiest choice may be to use the comment system natively supplied by your CMS / through plugins.
- If on the other hand your users will only be using the iOS app(s) for commenting (via a native interface) or you'll be heavily customizing the website anyway, using a comment system independent from your CMS might be an option.

**How will the content be accessed from the app?**

Via a simple web view? Or will the app download via an API provided by your CMS and display it in a native UI? If you are using an API provided by your CMS, you will have the same issue with your content as with your comments when moving CMSes.

- You could add an intermediate layer that abstracts from the specific CMS API.
- Or if you don't really plan on moving CMSes but want to prepare for that event nevertheless, you could simply implement a no-frills "version check" to ask the server for the CMS kind / version it is using, and if it doesn't match what your app expects, ask the users to update. This isn't the prettiest user experience, but it might be sufficient depending on what you're actually planning.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. It gives me a much better idea of going forward with this. Thanks again